# how do i write 1 to 7 days condition in if statement in matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
period=input('Enter the rental period:');
toc=menu('Select type of the car from menu.','Class B','Class C','Class D');
if period>60
   disp('Rental is not available for more than 60 days.')
else if period<7 & toc==3
   disp('Class D cars can not be rented for less than 7 days')
else if period=1<6 & toc==2
```

i am doing a calculation here and checking some conditions to get the cost of renting car.
i am stuck on the last line
how do i check whether the period is within 1 to  days or not?

Comment: `period>=1 & period<=7`  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍btw, I suspect that you might want to use `elseif` instead of `else if`

Answer (score 0):

Alternate Solution:

You can use the statement `B == a`, where a is a scalar and B is a Matrix, to make a matrix of booleans the size of B, where each boolean says whether B is equal to a. By combining this with `any()`, we see that `any([1:7] == period` will be true when the period is between 1 to 7.